# One template/layout for two or more applications in Symfony 1.4

Tags: templates, layout, symfony1

I'm working with symfony 1.4.8.

Is there a way to create one general template/layout for two or more applications?

Is this even possible in Symfony?

Thanks for helping.
Redstorm

Comment: You can consider Drupal if that is generally required for your development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a supported way to do that, plugins can only help you with modules/templates, not with the layout.

Your best option is to symlink/hardlink one layout to the other, so you don't need to update both manually.

Comment: Or use simple way - in each layout use include ('../../path/to/global_layout.php');

Comment: This is a workaround I hadn't thought about! Pretty good idea! but notice you need to configure the web server to follow symlinks...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article:

[Sharing layouts cross-application in symfony](http://www.gerryvandermaesen.com/posts/sharing-layouts-cross-application-in-symfony)

I ran into the same question and that's the one I found more symfony-like and clean. Hope you can still use it!